# C++ Simplifying classes/OOP approach

Tags: c++, oop

I am very new to C++, having only used Unrealscript previously, and I'm trying to write a relatively simple console game to teach myself the basics (using OneLoneCoder engine). I've set myself a goal of implementing pause/dialog screens which can call specific functions depending on player input (eg pressing Y or N when given an option, which could then lead to another dialog box, or something happening to the player). My first instinct was to create a base class like this:

```
wstring PauseText,PromptText;
PauseScreen CurrPauseScreen;

class PauseScreen
{
public:

    virtual wstring GetPText()
    {
        return L"NO PAUSE TEXT";
    }
    virtual wstring GetPPText()
    {
        return L"NO PROMPT TEXT";
    }

    virtual void EFunc()
    {
        UnPause();
    }

    virtual void YFunc()
    {

    }

    virtual void NFunc()
    {

    }

    virtual void SetPrompts()
    {
        PauseText = GetPText();
        PromptText = GetPPText();
    }

    PauseScreen()
    {
        SetPrompts();  
    }
    ~PauseScreen()
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
 if (m_keys[L'E'].bPressed || m_keys[L'P'].bPressed)
 {
    CurrPauseScreen->EFunc();
 }
 else if (m_keys[L'Y'].bPressed)
 {    
    CurrPauseScreen->YFunc();
 }
 else if (m_keys[L'N'].bPressed)
 {
   CurrPauseScreen->NFunc();
 }

 return 0;
}
```

and override functions as necessary. At the moment, I'm using a global CurrPauseScreen variable to store the currently used PauseScreen info, and simply take all necessary values and methods from that (remembering to delete it when game is unpaused or a new screen is created).
I initially attempted to use function pointers which pointed to class methods and didn't use the 'new' operator in order to avoid using heap memory because I know it's ill-advised, but I felt like I was chasing my own tail figuring out how to use them properly, as it doesn't seem easy to have a pointer point to a class method. Basically I want to know if there is a simpler way of setting/changing all necessary functions and variables through classes on a one-off basis, or if using classes and an Object-Oriented approach is advised at all in this situation, as from what I've seen through my google searching, it's often looked down upon in C++.
EDIT: The code I have at the moment works as I intended, but is just a little too 'messy' for my liking, having to place a class on the heap and ensure it's deleted appropriately at each step. Ideally I would like to simply instantiate a class on the stack and have the class handle all of the setting within itself, including changing the PauseText,PromptText and the various functions (EFunc(), YFunc() and NFunc()). Changing the text is easy enough, but changing function behaviour from within a class is where I am having the most trouble.

Comment: " as from what I've seen through my google searching, it's often looked down upon in C++." unclear what you mean. Object orientation is an important part of C++, though it isnt the only paradigm. Many problems where other languages use OO as the goto solution have other solutions in C++.

Comment: the question is rather unclear. Please focus on one specific issue and post a [mcve] of your code. There are no function pointers in your code and it is not clear what `PauseText` and `PromptText` are

Comment: Maybe I'm just coming across the snootier parts of C++ forums because I keep reading about how OOP is somehow obsolete or not 'fast' enough. Apologies for making my question too unclear; I'll make some edits to refine my point.

Comment: if you use runtime polymorphism when no runtime polymorphism is needed then you will notice that it isnt as fast as it could be. Maybe thats where your impression is coming from. Though, anything can be used for the wrong job, thats not special for OO in C++

Comment: As a general rule you will find a lot and I mean a *lot* of people with Important Opinions on C++, especially when it comes to how "slow" the object-oriented stuff is. Ignore them. Most have no idea what they're talking about, they're just parroting what they've heard, or they're complaining about how slow their code was which is almost always unrelated to C++ itself and more a function of how they attack their problems. C++ is very fast *if used properly*. The tricky part is knowing how to use it properly, but there's a lot of people here that can help steer you in the right direction.

Comment: You'll need to define exactly how "fast" the plumbing of your software must function to achieve its task, and whether the alternative is worth sacrificing clarity, simplicity and maintainability.  In general, this question requires more code + specification and less story telling.

Comment: Heap memory isn't "ill advised", it's not something to be feared or suspicious of. It is, however, something that comes with *responsibility*, as one of the important rules in C++ is [RIAA](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). If you allocate memory manually this complicates things, you need to unwind your own mess without depending on the stack to do it for you, which is where heap allocations can be challenging to deal with. Not slow, not difficult, just at times tedious as you must pay close attention or you'll *leak memory*.

Comment: Thank you all very much for responding. I apologise again if my question is perhaps a bit too vague for this site, I would just rather know the most efficient way of tackling a problem in C++ as I know it's powerful and I don't want to give myself training scars by treating it simply as a glorified UnrealScript.

Comment: Tips: Use a character drawing library like [NCurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html) if you can. These give you a lot of tools for drawing windows, taking input, capturing keystrokes, etc. which are extremely fussy to do by yourself using bare C++. Secondly, use [an event-loop architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), something that's the backbone of any [game engine](https://www.gameenginebook.com), be it graphical or text-based.

Comment: Don't be afraid of just using the tools you know and eventually running into their limitations.  That is how you learn.  You just simply cannot shortcut learning for everything that an experienced C++ developer instinctively knows.  How do you think they acquired that knowledge?  It is through years of practice.  And they also continue to learn and acquire new skills, drop old habits, develop new understandings, adopt better practices...

Comment: Learning how to tackle a problem in *any* language usually requires a good deal of experience. While there may be good "rules of thumb" in the end it often comes down to the exact problem (and even then there's often more than one way of solving it)